# Spring contextloaderlistener role in bean creation

Tags: java, spring

I looked at some of docs for `Contextloaderlistener` and application context and based on that what I understand is Application Context is the container initialized by a `ContextLoaderListener` and load all the spring config files. What I am not clear about is which one is responsible for the bean creation based on the meta data that is provided. Is it the `ContextLoaderListener` or the Application Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) creates the beans utilising a [BeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html), which is the actual component that turns xml/annotations into classes and manages the lifecycle of each.

A ContextLoaderListener is used when spring is running inside another container (eg a servlet engine like tomcat) to detect the startup of the application and initialise the ApplicationContext. When the spring is used in another context -eg a java program run through a main method - the application can create the AppContext directly without needing the ContextLoaderListener like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "context.xml");
    Foo foo = (Foo) ctx.getBean("fooBean");
    foo.doSomethingCool();
```

}
}

Comment: @Vaishu13 : did you find the answer that cleared your ambiguities ? If it is different, please share it with us.

Answer (score 3):

- The idea behind the **ApplicationContext** in Spring is that in order
  to    properly inject objects where they are needed, some thing needs
  to be    aware of the configuration the user specifies and inject
  dependencies    based on this configuration.
- The **ApplicationContext** is the thing that understands the user's
  wishes in terms of where and what should be injected (as well as
  other things such as AOP pointcuts and such) based on the
  configuration a user provides, either through an xml file or
  annotations.
- The context named after your servlet ( [servlet-name]-context.xml )
  is a **WebApplicationContext** and is a child context of the main
  **ApplicationContext**, which is created from the files listed in the contextConfigLocation and loaded by the ContextLoaderListener. The
  child can access any beans defined in the parent, but the parent has
  no access to beans defined in the child
- **ContextLoaderListener** is a ServletListener. So in the JSP/Servlet    spec a Servlet Listener gets called by the container when certain
  events occur. In this case it gets called right after when the
  ServletContext is created for the web application. When it gets
  called, inside the ContextLoaderListener it will create/instantiate
  an **ApplicationContext** and load in the xml file you set with the
  context-param name and value tags.
- The contextConfigLocation param is used in conjunction with this
  Spring listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
- ContextLoaderListener  executes the bootstrap of the listener to
  start up Spring's root WebApplicationContext
- ContextLoaderListener is a class that starts Spring container.
  Basically every Spring application consists of several beans and
  wiring (declarative description of which beans depend on each other).
  This description was historically written in XML (these days we have
  annotations, Java configuration, CLASSPATH scanning, etc.)
- **ContextLoaderListener reads that file, finds your classes,
  instantiates them and wires. All your beans are then placed inside a
  container.**